# How can you pass data to the next route without it showing up in the URL?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

There are multiple places in my app when I'd like to be able to do something like

Router.go 'foo', {}, {query: '', extra_data: {bar: 1}}

I don't want `bar` in the URL because I don't want it there on reload or history forward/back or when sharing the URL, I just need `bar` during the next `foo` action function that occurs.

Comment: may bes `session` or `client side collections`?

Comment: Yeah, Session's probably the easiest way to do it if there's nothing in IR

Answer (score 0):

It’s just this simple (assuming your code is CoffeeScript):

```
Router.go 'foo', {bar: 1}
```

Then in your next route, for example in `onBeforeAction`, you should have `@params.bar`.

Comment: Thanks, but for me, unless `foo` has `bar` in the path, eg `/foo/:bar`, @params.bar will be undefined.